# How do I change screensize requirements of bash programs?

Tags: terminal, resolution

If you use testdisk, btscanner or similar tools, they usually have a minimum screen size requirement, which means that those programs don't run on a bash size (in pixel) lower than the value required for the programs.

Now my question is, if this is *"hard coded"* into the programs, so that it is virtually impossible to change those requirements or is it more of a bash setting that is maybe changable?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "bash size".  Everywhere that you have written "bash" you should have written "terminal", it seems.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that bash is used to execute these things.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, a terminal is a text interface and does not represent any resolution or graphical representation.  Its operation depends on the terminal type specified in the `$TERM` variable which needs to be compatible with the terminal client used.

The number of characters per line and the number of rows is determined automatically by all common terminal clients based on the font they use and the window's dimensions.  This information is visible and changeable with `stty`.  `stty -a` will show you all the tty related settings.

Classic hardware terminals were typically 24 lines by 80 or 132 columns.  Using something smaller means that you're limiting yourself more than 40 year old technology.

As for the program requirements, there is no general universal rule and each program may have its own requirements.  Some may be more flexible than others and take related parameters, but most command line programs have fixed requirements or none.

`testdisk`'s only screen requirement is to have a minimum of 24 lines which is very minimalist.  As you can see when you run it, they aligned everything based on that 24 line model so just changing a number could mess up its display logic.